# Is there a CSS selector to locate nth element of a given type in the entire page?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have Selenium-based tests that validate a page with several H2 sections. The sections used to belong to the same parent, so it was easy to assert for an expected text using CSS selectors (I use FluentAutomation API):

```
I.Expect.Text("Section Title").In("h2:nth-of-type(2)")
```

Now the page design has changed, so H2 sections are placed under different DIVs, so each of them is now 1st child if its parent. Now the selector h2:nth-of-type(1) selects all H2 sections, and h2:nth-of-type(2) selects none.

I would like not to be dependent on the structure of DIVs when selecting H2 sections. What I am trying to achieve is to select nth element of H2 type across the entire page. I know this is easy using jQuery, but is this possible using CSS syntax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply change the target to point to your new `<div>` elements instead:

```css
div:nth-of-type(1) h2 { ... }
div:nth-of-type(2) h2 { ... }
```

This obviously depends on how many divider elements are on your page. If you are using dividers not just to contain `<h2>` elements you could always give them a new class:

```html
<div class="h2-container">
    <h2>Hello, world!</h2>
</div>
```

```css
div.h2-container:nth-of-type(1) h2 { ... }
div.h2-container:nth-of-type(2) h2 { ... }
```

This does assume that all your divider elements are under the same parent, however.

Comment: Well, the path of H2 sections is quite long, here are two of them:

/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[1]/h2
/html/body/div[3]/div/div[1]/div[5]/div/div[1]/h2

This means I can't simply use div:nth-of-type(1)/div:nth-of-type(2). What works is something like this:

div:nth-of-type(3) div:nth-of-type(3) h2
div:nth-of-type(3) div:nth-of-type(5) h2

But then I am _very_ dependent on div structure, and I'd like to avoid it and to find a way to locate the first and the second H2 across the _entire_ page. Getting the first is never a problem, but others are worse.

Comment: Is your page content generated dynamically? If so, can you not simply add a class to every *n* `<h2>` element?

Comment: Yes, it's generated dynamically, and yes, I believe the easiest is just to add a class to the elements I need to locate in tests. I just wanted to know if there is a standard CSS selector to locate nth element across the entire page. It does not look so.
Thanks for the help!